# How to change localhost landing page from root?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

So I have 2 routes which are `/first` and `/second`. And when I go to `http://localhost:3000/` I cannot see anything because I have nothing on the root (`/`). So I was wondering if it is possible to make `http://localhost:3000/` redirect straight to `http://localhost:3000/review` or is there any other way to make it possible?

```
<Router history={history}>
    <div>
        <Route
            path="/first"
            render={() => <myComponent />}
            exact
        />
        <Route
            path="/second"
            render={() => <secondComponent />}
        />
    </div>
/>
```

Comment: Yes, you can do that using `<Redirect>`. You can refer
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md

Comment: <Redirect from="/" to="first" />; add <Redirect> router

Comment: Nice! Thanks!
Currently getting this warning: warning.js:34 Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on: "first"
Will see if I can figure out how to avoid that

Comment: And getting this warning even when I am already in "/second"

Comment: From a GH issue I found a solution. It was to wrap the Router content inside a Switch instead of a div

Answer (score 0):

Redirect has to be added after `Route`'s and everything to be wrapped inside a `Switch`.

```
      <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route
            path="/review"
            render={() => <RateReviewStep cancelRateReview={this.cancelRateReview} />}
            exact
          />
          <Route
            path="/confirm"
            render={() => <RateConfirmationStep model={model} fields={fields} />}
          />
          <Redirect from="/" to="review" />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
```